# Closed form for sum of modulo remainders

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Given a set of natural numbers {$N_1, ...N_n$} and another natural number $N$, find a closed form solution for the below sum

$M = \sum_{i=1}^n N_i \% N$ 
    where $N_i, N, n \in \mathbb N$
    and $N_i \% N$ is the remainder when $N_i$ is divided by $N$

Although trivial, I was able to reduce it to the below form
$M = KN + (\sum_{i=1}^n N_i)\%N$
   where $K$ is the quotient when $M$ is divided by N
but I am unable to reduce $K$ further into any closed form.

I don't have any formal proof that a closed form can exist, but belief that one could exist has driven be into looking for a solution.
I have been looking up several research papers and questions posted here, but could not get any pointers. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What makes you think there is a closed form?

Comment: Also: $\{N_0,\dots,N_n\}$ is $n+1$ numbers, not $n$ numbers.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Oops that right, it should start from $N_1$ not $N_0$.

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee K is the quotient when M is divided by N

Comment: @StevenClark I have modified the question to reduce confusions, wrt random. Please let me know if this clarifies your doubts. Distinct implied $N_i \neq N_j$, which is optional, just in case it helped to arrive at a solution quicker. $N$ can be any other number either inside or outside the set of {$N_i$} and $M$ is just the representation of the actual sum.

Comment: Ok, so arbitrary versus random. It seems to me finding a closed form for $M=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n N_i$ where each $N_i$ in the arbitrary set of integers $\{N_1, ... N_n\}$ is restricted to $0\le N_i<N$ isn't really any easier of a problem, is it?

Comment: @StevenClark $M \neq \sum_{i=1}^n N_i$, but it is the sum of remainders $M = \sum_{i=1}^n N_i \% N$. Also, $N$ has no relation to $N_i$, so there is no such restriction as $0 < N_i < N$.

Comment: I understand your question, but I'll attempt to clarify my point using different variable names since reusing your variable names seems to have caused some confusion. The mod operation maps the values of $N_i$ to $0\le K_i<N$ where $K_i=N_i \% N$. I was just pointing out that finding a closed form for $J=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n K_i$ where each $K_i$ in an arbitrary set of integers $\{K_1, ... K_n\}$ is restricted to $0\le K_i<N$ doesn't seem to be any easier than finding a closed form for $M=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n N_i \% N$.

Comment: I don't see how either could have a closed form unless you consider a finite sum (which you already have) a closed form.

Comment: Oh! i understand it now. May be my understanding of closed form is different, may be even wrong. What I searching for is to represent $K$ as a function of $n$, $N$ and some $f(N_i)$. An example would be the sum of natural number 1+2+3+ ... n = n(n+1)/2, a formula where I can avoid running through the numbers to compute the sum. Is something like this possible?

Comment: Basically I want to separate $N$ from $N_i$, so that all operations on $N_i$ can be pre-computed, instead of computing the mod every time I get a $N$.